# Put Value to Empty Location in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++17

I have this method

```cpp
public: void reserveMemory(int start, i32 space) {
    for (int index = start; index < start + space; index++)
    {
        this->memory.at(index) = (i32)0;
    }
}
```

and when `this->memory.at(index)` is empty it throws an error. How am I going to put a value to that location when the index is empty?

Notes:

- `this->memory` is a `std::vector<i32>`.
- `i32` is `int32_t` and defined with `typedef int32_t i32;`.
- This is in a class.

Exception message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE4E8CD759 in Tests.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location.

Comment: Replace your loop with `this->memory.resize(start+space)`?

Comment: I need to put `(i32)0`.

Comment: Write that up and call it a day @Some programmer dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the loop, all you need is to [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) the vector:

```
void reserveMemory(int start, i32 space) {
    memory.resize(start + space);
}
```

The new elements that are created will be zero-initialized.

Note that this kind of makes the name of the function (`reserveMemory`) wrong since you don't actually [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) memory, but actually resizes the vector. Reserving and resizing is semantically different.

Comment: So if I do `object.reserveMemory(0, 5); std::cout << this->memory.at(2) << "\n"` it will print 0 right?

Comment: By the way the `resizeMemory` is the virtual machine's memory, not the actual memory.

Comment: Anyways, it worked. Thank you @Some programmer dude.